# Ninject DI causing deployment issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to deploy a website that uses Ninject for DI which works well locally on my development machine (don't they all!).
When deployed to my host (using the visual studio ftp publish option) I get the following error:

```
Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'.
```

and

```
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Website.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
```

Looking at the stack trace it appears **NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType)** is the method that is failing.
As I say, its working fine locally so don't really know where or how to being tackling this one. Googleing hasn't brought up anything useful.

I'm using Ninject 3.0.1.10 if thats relevant.

**Edit:** I've since added paramterless constructors to the homecontroller, but it has made no difference and the same error exists....

Comment: Do you have all of the relevant/needed dlls copy local set to true?  Sounds like you are missing some assemblies.

Comment: Are you sure the server is running .NET 4?

Comment: @Mystere Man: The detailed error page shows Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: @Tommy: I've set System.web.webhost, system.web.selfhost, system.web.data.helpers, system.web.data.entityframework, system.web.http.data, system.web.helpers and ninject.dll all to copy always

Comment: @LDJ - are you using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: @Mystere Man: Changed the target framework to 4.0 (default in VS2012 is of course 4.5) and its working. Post your response as an answer if you want and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are building against .NET 4.5 and deploy on .NET 4.0 or you deploy Ninject for .NET 4.5 on .NET 4.0

Comment: Yep, changed the version to 4.0 et voila!

Comment: Everytime I have a ninject issue, the process is the same.  Google=>stackoverflow=>Remo's answer=>success.